# Mapping between two sets as a dictionary

Tags: set-theory

I have two sets $A = \{a1,...,a_n\}, B = \{b_1,...,b_m\}$, for some $n,m$ and with $m \leq n$. I want to map some elements from $A$ to $B$, based on the following assumptions:

1. each item of $A$ can only have one corresponding item of $B$ as a mapping;
2. there is the possibility that some items of $A$ could not have a mapping with $B$.

I want to write formally this problem. My idea is the following: define a mapping $M : B \mapsto A$, that is creating the set $(b_j,a_i) | b_j \in B \wedge a_i \in A$ if $\exists ! b_j : a_i \subseteq b_j$, $\emptyset$ otherwise, for $i=1,...,n$ and $j=1,...,m$.

Note that by saying $a_i \subseteq b_j$ I am referring to the fact that $a_i$ could be seen as a sub-category of a macro-category $b_j$.

My doubts are on the indexes $i,j$, i.e. $a_1,a_3,a_{10}$ could be mapped to $b_5$. Am I using them correctly when I'm saying "for $i=1,...,n$ and $j=1,...,m$"?

What I want to achieve is similar to a dictionar implementation, i.e. having the elements of the set $B$ as keys, and the elements of $A$ as values, with the possibility of having some keys without any values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you have reversed the role of $A, B$ half-way through your question. It seems that the thing you are describing is a _partial function_ from $A$ to $B$ (in the first part of your question) or from $B$ to $A$ (in the second part of your question).

Comment: So the function would have to be $M : A \mapsto B$?